# Visualforce Checkbox Rerender via Ajax - Whats wrong with my code?

Tags: rerender, actionsupport, inputcheckboxes, pageblock

I want to disable the pageblock section when the checkbox is checked,enable it when the check box is unchecked. I had tried with rerender but it is not working as expected.

> Note:The checkbox is placed inside another pageblock

```
<apex:pageBlock>
   <apex:outputLabel >Payment accepted</apex:outputLabel>

   <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!testCheck }">
      <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!updateTestCheck}" reRender="casePB" status="statusSaveTrip" />
   </apex:inputCheckbox>
</apex:pageBlock>

<apex:pageBlock id="casePB">
   <apex:outputpanel>
      <apex:outputLabel >Customer Wants:</apex:outputLabel>

      <apex:selectList value="{!Customerselectedid}"  multiselect="false" size="1" >
         <apex:selectOptions value="{!customerwantoptions}"></apex:selectOptions>
         <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="casePB" action="{!enableCCButton}" status="statusSaveTrip"/>
      </apex:selectlist>

      <apex:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-primary btn-xs"  value="Create Case"  action="{!logACase}" disabled="{!isCaseButton}" status="statusSaveTrip"/>
   </apex:outputpanel>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Even instead of disable/enable we can hide/show pageblock also. Any pointers on this?

Comment: Are you changing the value of `isCaseButton` in your `updateTestCheck` method?

Comment: Yes @CasparHarmer , i am updating the disabled property of command button only when the checkbox is unchecked. The updtaeTestCheck() is going to execute only when the checkbox is unchecked

Comment: Can you please check my answer and close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that you are changing checkbox values in the controller method.

You can wrap pageblock into an `outputPanel` and rerender the outputPanel from `actionSupport` call.

Display the pageblock based on checkbox is checked.

Below is the code:

```
<apex:pageBlock>
   <apex:outputLabel >Payment accepted</apex:outputLabel>

   <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!testCheck }">
      <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!updateTestCheck}" reRender="panel1" status="statusSaveTrip" />
   </apex:inputCheckbox>
</apex:pageBlock>

<apex:outputpanel id="panel1" >
<apex:pageBlock id="casePB" rendered={!testCheck}>   
      <apex:outputLabel >Customer Wants:</apex:outputLabel>

      <apex:selectList value="{!Customerselectedid}"  multiselect="false" size="1" >
         <apex:selectOptions value="{!customerwantoptions}"></apex:selectOptions>
         <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="casePB" action="{!enableCCButton}" status="statusSaveTrip"/>
      </apex:selectlist>

      <apex:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-primary btn-xs"  value="Create Case"  action="{!logACase}" disabled="{!isCaseButton}" status="statusSaveTrip"/>

</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:outputpanel>
```